# If one Starship can transport 100 people to Mars, how many could it safely land near Mercury's north pole after one Hohmann-like transfer?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, spacex-starship, hohmann-transfer, mercury

Personally, I would rather live near Mercury's north pole than anywhere on Mars mainly because:

- [The permanently shadowed craters harbor abundant water ice and other frozen volatile materials](https://nasa.gov/mission_pages/messenger/media/PressConf20121129.html)
- Mercury receives **15 times as much solar energy** on average as Mars does.
- [Mercury's crust has carbon-bearing material](https://researchgate.net/publication/297658787_Remote_sensing_evidence_for_an_ancient_carbon-bearing_crust_on_Mercury), combined with the solar energy suitable to extract metals from their minerals and oxides, i.e. to perform [pyrometallurgy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrometallurgy) with [concentrated solar power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentrated_solar_power).
- At **80⁰ N latitude** the subsurface temperature below 1 m depth is a **constant 0⁰ C**, independent of the diurnal surface temperature variation.  (Values derived from [this article](https://luna1.diviner.ucla.edu/%7Edap/pubs/019.pdf))

**But it's been stated many times that it's so hard to get there because of the proximity of the Sun.**

From the BBC news article ["What is Elon Musk's Starship?"](https://bbc.com/news/science-environment-55564448):

> "You could conceivably have five or six people per cabin, if you really wanted to crowd people in. But I think mostly we would expect to see two or three people per cabin, and so nominally about **100 people per flight to Mars**," Musk said.
> The payload bay would also host common areas, storage space, a galley and a shelter where people could gather to shield from solar storms, where the Sun belches out harmful charged particles into space.

I really would like to know how many people could be transported **to the surface of Mercury's north pole** with  such a Starship, taking into account the longer trajectory to the aphelion of Mercury's orbit than that to an orbit around Mars.

**Please with the necessary calculations to be able to control the assertions in your answer !**

Comment: Read up on the route taken by the [Messenger probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESSENGER#Launch_and_trajectory).  It took 6½ _years_ to get to Mercury.  It's about as hard as getting to Saturn.

Comment: Also, the "100 people on a starship" is an *Elon Number*, i.e. the same as a Trump number with twice the inaccuracy. A quick back-of-the-envelope calculation shows it is beyond sane, see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SummGvYrHqw

Comment: Getting to Mercury directly is ridiculously hard - A landing mission needs about the same $\Delta v$ as landing on Pluto!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*I take* "after one Hohmann-like transfer" *to mean a direct Earth to Mercury interplanetary transfer (i.e., no Venus shenanigans), please let me know if that is not the case.*

---

Unless serious [lithobraking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithobraking) is possible, no humans will go to Mercury.

Starship, even with no payload, doesn't have the juice to do anything other than fly by Mercury:

- [120t dry mass](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/54345/40257) + [1200t of propellant](https://www.spacex.com/vehicles/starship/) + [380s $I_{sp}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor) $\to$ $\Delta V$ = ~$8940m/s$

I did a trajectory search from 2025-2030 from Earth to Mercury direct transfers. The cheapest launch $\Delta V$ (from a 250 km LEO) is **4.87 km/s** (red dot, $C3=$~$40$ $km^2/s^2$, L: 27-Nov-2026, A: 23-Mar-2027):

[image: min launch dV]
(personal work)

Sounds nice, but the arrival speed (Mercury relative speed @ 0 altitude) for these specific dates is a cool **13.65 km/s** (*yikes!*). In fact, the minimum arrival speed for the period examined is **8.91 km/s**, only slightly less (0.3%) than the total $\Delta V$ the *payload-less Starship* has available.

So if you could throw a fully fueled, *yet still empty*, Starship at Mercury on that trajectory (L: 09-May-2029, A: 31-Mar-2030, $C3=$~$104$ $km^2/s^2$**!**) you might have a shot at landing safely. Good luck!

---

**Edit:**
A premise of the question is incorrect:

> taking into account the longer trajectory to the aphelion of Mercury's orbit than that to an orbit around Mars

The transfer time to Mercury (for the launch example) is only ~120 days, less than half of a typical transfer to Mars. The minimum arrival speed example uses a longer type III/IV trajectory (I didn't check which & it doesn't really matter), yet is still comparable to a typical Mars transfer at ~330 days.

Comment: Could you mention the source of the diagram in the answer ?

Comment: If  one Venus flyby would appear to be advantageous and you like to do the calculations, please do so !

Comment: @Cornelis source is personal work. That's not how the question reads, but if I have some time I may consider it.

Comment: I think you could earn (or have earned) more points with your answer if you explained how you got the numbers you show with some equations, because many readers (like me) are not that familiar with the stuff like you apparently are. For example, mass +$ I_sp$ (is it 1200 t propellant ?) becomes delta v ? And how do you calculate C3 from delta v ? Why is it worth mentioning C3 ? Then yuo go from a cool 13.65 km/s to a minimum of 8.91 km/sec. The cheapest delta v is 4.87 km/sec, what is the equation with which you got this number ? I would like to *learn* from your answer !

Comment: @Cornelis those are different questions that have mostly been answered on this site: [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35836/40257), [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/16863/40257), and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26563/40257) for starters

Comment: @Cornelis if you'd like an explanation on how to produce such a plot and how to interpret it (get values like $\Delta V$ etc.), you would have to ask those questions

Comment: Very interesting. Presumably a modified Starship with stretched tanks as now seems likely and with other modifications might be in with a chance?

Comment: @Slarty maybe, I haven't seen any numbers for a stretched Starship though so can't even guess

Comment: Come for the math, stay for the Venus shenanigans.

Answer (score 17):

The delta-v to Mercury is [2.5x greater than to Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget); given the dry mass of Starship I doubt that it could land any payload at all without some heliocentric fuel depot, which would be quite tricky and expensive to set up.  This is without taking into consideration that Starship just isn't designed to survive the heat it would absorb by traveling so close to the sun; Mercury-bound spacecraft have to be [specially designed to handle the temperatures.](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/BepiColombo/High_temperature_challenge)

Comment: Heliocentric fuel depots won't be helpful unless you throw them along the exact same transfer orbit as the spacecraft is on, in which case, you might as well attach them to the spacecraft itself, and they become extra stages or drop tanks.

Comment: Not to mention that you can aerobrake at Mars, there's no aerobrake at Mercury.

Answer (score 13):

Landing on Mercury is supremely difficult due to how deep Mercury lies in the Suns gravitational well. In addition it has no significant atmosphere so retro propulsive landings would be required making it harder still.

It is very unlikely that Starship would be a good choice for landing on Mercury owing to it's high mass, it can't be ruled out entirely, but it would certainly need considerable modification. Stretched tanks, lowered payload capacity and more.

It would also be necessary to re-tank in a very highly elliptical Earth orbit to maximise it's capability and use a fleet of disposable tankers. But even that might not be enough. Another option would be a series of gravitational assists from the Earth and Venus. That might just do it but at the cost of a very extended mission duration with subsequent problems of crew exposure to radiation and zero gravity, crew life support requirements and the practicality of retaining cryogenic propellants for many years.

In summary. It's not going to happen.

Comment: A light-weight heat shield could be attached on one half of the spacecraft to protect against both radiation and high temperature exposure.

Comment: A light weight heat shield will do very little to protect against radiation. You will either need a great deal of mass, or a magnetic shield which at present is purely theoretical.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Could not slowly rotating the spacecraft help ? And there's also radiative cooling. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_cooling#Heat_Shields

Comment: @Cornelis [this kind of radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionizing_radiation)

Comment: @BrendanLuke15: Wouldn't the worst of the ionizing radiation (the high-energy galactic cosmic radiation coming from distant supernovae and such) be _less_ of a problem deeper in the sun's magnetosphere (leaving only the lower-energy radiation from the sun itself)?

Comment: @Vikki GCRs aren't really "the worst of the ionizing radiation", they're just the kind with the highest energy per-particle. Increasing the lower-energy, but still dangerous solar radiation by an order of magnitude to somewhat reduce a component of the radiation that's mainly relevant to long-term exposure is a poor trade.

Comment: Would you mind adding a couple sentences to further explain your first sentence?  Thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLz look at this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0uwtmHt0v4

The hole in the middle is the Sun, the coins the planets. Much faster at the bottom of the funnel A vast difference in orbital speed that must be taken into account when changing orbits. The orbital speed of the planets can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed#Planets

Any kind of image of the solar system based on A road map is hopeless. Better to imagine this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3HXVfz8r4A
Imagine playing catch with someone doing 60mph around the middle of the spinner

Comment: @Slarty Thank you.  I will watch & read the references you provided.